# How to set automatic download dependencies to JMeter slave machines from JMeter Maven Plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I was using `<jmeterExtensions>` tag to specify the dependency plugins although the dependencies are not getting downloaded for slave machines where It is required to manually download them in slave machine. Is there any solution to download dependencies to slave machines as well.

Comment: Your tag was being formatted as HTML and did not show in the visible post.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok you should accept it and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not handled by [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/) and I don't think it can be implemented there.

So the option would be to run a kind of warmup on every machine using remote ssh and launching maven on it.

You could try to automate this using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/).

See this [blog](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/shift-left-performance-tests-jmeter-maven/) for more details on using the plugin.